# Mapping a no-args function to REST

Tags: rest

Let's imagine you have a REST resource `Restriction` (think of a roadblock) that has some filters (e.g. street, direction etc.). The restriction has an `expiry` which is a datetime. It is only considered in the application logic, when the expiry is in the future or unset/null (no expiry).

Now with procedural style, I could just have a method on the restriction saying `expire()` which would set the expiry to the current time.

With REST we modify the state of resources instead. I am torn between these more or less functionally equivalent API definitions:

```
PATCH /restrictions/{id}
data = {
  "expiry": 1558654742
}
```

Client explicitly sets the expiry. This bears the risk of user error with time zones, wrong host clocks etc. Also the client is not supposed to have any choice other than current time.

```
PATCH /restrictions/{id}
data = {
  "expired": true
}
```

The `expired` field is a transient virtual property that is translated on the backend to `expiry = now`. This might be confusing for clients. Also the value for `expired` can be only `true`, so there's some redundancy here.

```
DELETE /restrictions/{id}
```

Resource stays persisted (soft delete), but is not returned by GET on the collection, which only returns non-expired restrictions. There is no GET on individual restrictions.

```
PUT /restrictions/{id}/expiry
data = {}
```

Creates a new virtual resource (no other methods on this path) which represents the expiry. Not sure whether PUTs without any data are idiomatic though.

---

Right now I do not plan on returning individual restrictions, and the list of all restrictions will return only the non-expired ones by default.

Which one of those methods would you consider the most idiomatic and obvious for a RESTful web service?

Answer (score 0):

If the resource will return a 404 after expiring, `DELETE` is a great method for this.

Comment: Right now I don't have a use case for fetching individual restrictions, only a list of un-expired ones.

Answer (score 0):

> Which one of those methods would you consider the most idiomatic and obvious for a RESTful web service?

If you want idiomatic REST, think about how you would do it with a web site.

You'd probably start with `GET /restrictions/{id}`, and in addition to data about the restriction there would be a form -- maybe embedded in the representation, maybe in the representation of another resource but available via link.  You would then submit that form, which would bundle up the fields into an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` docement included in a `POST` request.  You could use any URI as the action of the form (and therefore the target-uri of the POST request), but the most useful would probably be `POST /restrictions/{id}`, because HTTP compliant clients will know to [invalidate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) any previously cached representations of `/restrictions/{id}`.

> Right now I do not plan on returning individual restrictions, and the list of all restrictions will return only the non-expired ones by default.

Same game, but instead of using an identifier for the individual restriction, you would use the uri for the-list-of-non-expired-restrictions.  Your resource model doesn't have to match your data model.

There's no rule that says the content-type of a `POST` must be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  You could post other representations, including your own custom types if that makes things easlier (of course, you have to document the type, and the only clients that are going to send the type are those that have implemented it; the big advantage to the standard media types is that you get lots of clients "for free".)

`PUT` and `PATCH` are acceptable alternatives if modifying representations directly seems reasonable.  `PUT` (and probably `PATCH`, by inference) doesn't actually require that the server accepts the requests as is:

> A successful PUT of a given representation would suggest that a subsequent GET on that same target resource will result in an equivalent representation being sent in a 200 (OK) response.
>
> However, there is no guarantee that such a state change will be observable, since the target resource might be acted upon by other user agents in parallel, or might be subject to dynamic processing by the origin server, before any subsequent GET is received.  A successful response only implies that the user agent's intent was achieved at the time of its processing by the origin server.

There are conventions to be followed in the response that distinguish "I accepted your representation as is" from other responses.

Answer (score 0):

One of the few constraints REST has is the one of [cacheability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Cacheability). The constraints, as the name implies, are, according to Fielding, [not an option](https://www.infoq.com/articles/roy-fielding-on-versioning/), even though he talked about hypermedia in this context. Though the general rule applies here as well.

Caching allows local or intermediary applications, so called caches, to store the response of a certain URI for a certain amount of time and if a further safe request for that same URI hits the cache, the cache will serve the client with its stored response rather then routing the request to the server.

In case of your expiration you need to include thoughts about the expiration of such cached values as well, otherwise caches might still serve clients with data that shouldn't exist further.

HTTP talks about caching in [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) in detail and responses may tell a cache for how long a resource should be considered fresh via either the [Cache-Control](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2) header or the [Expires](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3) header. If both are present the former one wins. In example a response header such as `Cache-Control: max-age=3600` defines that a response should be considered fresh for up to 3600 seconds while `Expires` should use a date-time format specified in [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1) such as `Expires: Fri, 24 May 2019 05:20:00 CET`.

Unfortunately though, RFC 7234 does not talk about how a client can set such a directive actively, as this is considered a server task. `Cache-Control` does provide some [request headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1), though these are more of indications that a client either will or wont accept stale data, but not directives to the server to set a respective expiration date. Usually, if a client does not want a certain resource to be further available it should `DELETE` the resource. If you read up on [DELETE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) though, you might be astonished that it actually does not guarantee that the resource will ever be removed at all. All it states is, that after successfully processing such a request the mapping of the URI to the resource is removed. Whether the same resource is accessible through a different URI or not is not is a different story. "Customizing" `DELETE` with some kind of parameter to remove the resource after a certain amount of time might work for your API, though might not be understandable for different kind of APIs, therefore this is not recommendable in general.

By using `PATCH` the information on the expiration timestamp needs to be part of the resource itself. Usually such an information is considered a meta data of a resource and not the or part of the actual data. Therefore I'm not in favor for `PATCH` either, though this is clearly an opinionated take.

If all of the [other HTTP methods](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) do not fit the bill, [POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) should be taken, as here the server will process the request according to its own semantic. It may apply different heuristics upon receiving different payloads on the same endpoint as well. If you'd have to design such a feature on the Web you may have an edit page of an entry where you have the option to set an expiration date. Upon clicking the submit button of the form your browser is performing a `POST` request, including the expiration date, and the server will know what to do based on certain heuristics available on the server. I.e. the availability of the expiration date field in the request may instruct the server to actually queue a removal of the entry, update the expiration date meta data of the target resource and return an updated `Cache-Control: max-age=...` or `Expires: ...` header on incoming requests to also inform caches about not shipping cached responses of that resource past that time point.

Usually, [unsafe operations, like `POST`, `PUT` or `DELETE` invalidate cached responses of a target resource](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) by default, in a case where two users perform cacheable `GET` requests against a server, both having an intermediary cache in between that differs from the intermediary cache of the other user, and user 1 now expires the origin resource, there might be a case where user 2 will still get served by "his" intermediary cache for the target resource, even though the resource was already deleted on the origin server as his intermediary cache still sees the response as fresh enough and therefore serves use 2 with that stored response. The cached response of the target URI in user 1's cache should already have been removed by the initial `POST` request but also any eventually cacheable response might have returned an updated cache header and thus led to an expiration at the specified time point. It is therefore important to set the time values for the cache not to high into the future, but also not to short so that caching gets useless.

For resources that may be critical to get removed and not served by caches, in order to prevent the above mentioned case it is probably best to specify `Cache-Control: no-cache` in general so that such entries are not stored by caches further and requests are directly processed by the API/server itself.

To sum up this post, something like an expiration time point should be considered meta-data of a resource and not main-data. While `DELETE` may sound great at first, it does not support a removal after some time and an other API might perform such a request immediately, besides not guaranteeing to really remove that resource at all. `POST`, as the all-purpose toolset of HTTP, or other HTTP operations such as `PUT` or `PATCH` may be used here as well, even though the latter "work" under the premise that the body of a request belongs to the actual data of the resource. You should also consider caching into your design and use either `Cache-Control: max-age=...` or `Expires: ...` if your resource is non-critical or `Cache-Control: no-cache` in case of resources that must not ever (for whatever reason) return outdated information to clients. Regardless of the HTTP method you use, you should also think about how the server is allowing the client to set this option in general. Similar to the Web, a form-based solution avoids out-of-band information and thus simplifies the interaction with the API in general, as all of the information are already provided or are obtainable via further links.